# Indexes on super/parent SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a database schema as shown below.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`parent`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`parent` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`OtherTable`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`OtherTable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`parent_has_OtherTable`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`parent_has_OtherTable` (
  `parent_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `OtherTable_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`, `OtherTable_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx` (`OtherTable_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx` (`parent_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`parent` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`OtherTable_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`OtherTable` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`child`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`child` (
  `parent_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `andAnotherTable_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_child_parent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`parent` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;  

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I wish to perform the following two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM child
INNER JOIN parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=parent.id
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id
WHERE child.parent_id=123

SELECT *
FROM child
INNER JOIN parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=parent.id
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id
WHERE OtherTable.id=123
```

Is there any reason I need to include the `parent` table in my query (assuming I don't need any data in it), and instead do the queries like the following?  My concern is that maybe the indexes will no longer work since the indexes are between `parent` and `parent_has_OtherTable` and not `child` and `parent_has_OtherTable`.  PS.  I have other tables similar to `child` which have one-to-one relationships with `parent`, thus the reason my schema is the way it is.

```
SELECT *
FROM child
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=child.parent_id
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id
WHERE child.parent_id=123

SELECT *
FROM child
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=child.parent_id
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id
WHERE OtherTable.id=123



mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM child INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=child.parent_id INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id WHERE child.parent_id=1;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type  | possible_keys                                                                         | key                                  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | child                 | const | PRIMARY                                                                               | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const |    1 |                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parent_has_OtherTable | ref   | PRIMARY,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx | fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx | 4       | const |    2 | Using index                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | OtherTable            | ALL   | PRIMARY                                                                               | NULL                                 | NULL    | NULL  |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM child INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=child.parent_id INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id WHERE OtherTable.id=1;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type  | possible_keys                                                                         | key                                      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | OtherTable            | const | PRIMARY                                                                               | PRIMARY                                  | 4       | const |    1 |                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parent_has_OtherTable | ref   | PRIMARY,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx | fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx | 4       | const |    2 | Using index                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | child                 | ALL   | PRIMARY                                                                               | NULL                                     | NULL    | NULL  |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Indexes* never span tables. A foreign key makes reference to another table, but the FK utilizes an index defined in the table with the FK, referencing a unique index in the referenced table.

You should be able to test whether the indexes are being used, by analyzing a query with `EXPLAIN`. For example, you can see each table reference shows some index being used in the **key** field:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM child 
INNER JOIN parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id 
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=parent.id 
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id 
WHERE child.parent_id=123\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: child
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: parent
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: parent_has_OtherTable
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: OtherTable
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: mydb.parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
```

And for the second query, it also uses indexes:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM child 
INNER JOIN parent ON parent.id=child.parent_id 
INNER JOIN parent_has_OtherTable ON parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id=parent.id 
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON OtherTable.id=parent_has_OtherTable.OtherTable_id 
WHERE OtherTable.id=123\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: OtherTable
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: parent_has_OtherTable
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx,fk_parent_has_OtherTable_parent1_idx
          key: fk_parent_has_OtherTable_OtherTable1_idx
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: child
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: mydb.parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: parent
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: mydb.parent_has_OtherTable.parent_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: NULL
```

---

Re your comment and edited question:

Right, since `child` has a 1:1 relationship to `parent`, there should be no need to include parent in the join. The reasons to include parent would be if you need some columns from parent, or else row restriction -- that is, there may be fewer parent_id values in parent than in child (but this is kind of not possible by definition, because no value can appear in child that isn't also in parent).

Finally, I guess the general principle is: you can do a join based on any columns that contain the same logical domain of values -- they *don't* have to be part of an explicit foreign key relationship.

Comment: Thanks Bill,  The two queries which you used `EXPLAIN` on both joined `parent`.  I therefore ran them myself for queries that did not join parent, and posted the results under my original post.  Do I understand you correctly that indexes don't span tables, therefore, there is no reason I need to JOIN parents?